# How VPD is accessed via SMBus/I2C in a pci device?

Tags: linux, pci

Similar to what IPMI is querying, how will I access VPD of every device in a target server via SMBus/I2C? Do I need a driver for this or the i2c-dev module is enough? How to verify which is which on a target bus if I have several storage devices connected to a server?

I am using i2cdetect to verify i2c bus, however, I can't verify which bus my device is connected or does it have a bus in the first place. I know for a fact that I need an i2c bus/adapter to determine the actual i2c device. Creating an i2c client can do so but I still need to verify its bus connection and, creating an i2c client makes it limited to define i2c devices as enumerated in the id_table. As much as possible I want it to detect all storage devices regardless if it does have an i2c device or not.

i2cdetect outputs:

```
i2c-0   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x90             I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x91             I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x92             I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x93             I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x94             I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x95             I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x96             I2C adapter
i2c-7   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x97             I2C adapter
i2c-8   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at f000          SMBus adapter
```

i2cdetect -y 8 output:

```
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
    00:          -- -- -- -- -- 08 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    10: -- -- -- -- 14 15 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    30: 30 -- 32 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    40: -- -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    50: 50 51 52 53 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6e -- 
    70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Any replies will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make much sense out of your question. Assuming you have an embedded system with several I2C adapters, and have I2C clients connected to the busses. The first step is to describe in your question what system you have, what I2C adapters it has, and what clients are connecting to it on the hardware level. If there are drivers for your adapters, look at `dmesg` and under `/sys/bus/i2c` if they show up. You can communicate with I2C clients over the interface, but I'm not aware of any drivers for IPMI-like protocols, so you have to implement those protocols yourself.

Comment: Big thanks for the reply Sir. I have an eeprom connected to nvme device. Similar to what IPMI is querying, IPMI can query eeprom's VPD information on every nvme slot. I just would like to know how IPMI is querying these info. If I use i2cdetect which determines the i2c devices in the system, I really dont know where my device is connected. How come IPMI can detect these VPD info on every slot in the system? Im pretty much aware on how to query information if i2c-* bus is known and the address, however, I really dont have any idea how to determine the exact bus in the system? any idea Sir?

Comment: Additional info Sir. As I said, I have a nvme device with eeprom on it, I want to access VPD information of my device via SMBus/I2C. I already have a code for querying but it needs input parameters of /dev/i2c-* and address of the eeprom. I already have the address however, I am clueless on how to know which i2c-* my device is plugged in. Is this approach ok? its something like how IPMI is querying the same information. thanks for any information.

Comment: Guess: The IPMI BMC has this information somewhere in its firmware. Also, the I2C adapters in the BMC are not necessarily the same or in the same order as the I2C adapters on the host. If you are looking for an eeprom, `i2cdetect` works fairly reliably, and the eeproms usually have well-known addresses. Can you edit your question with the output of `i2cdetect` for all adapters?

Comment: Thanks again Sir. Updated question to add i2cdetect output. I've read BMC however I was not able to dig into that deeply since I cant see any source code related to this. Regarding i2cdetect, thats my problem, I dont know if i2cdetect can determine where my eeprom device is or does it display in the first place. What I see in the list are a bunch of VGA i2c and an SMBus adapter, after i loaded i2c-i801 module. I have 5 pci slot, 2 of which are x16. 1 VGA card inserted and 1 nvme device with eeprom in it. How you can give me an idea on how to retrieve or determine wheres my eeprom? thanks again

Comment: Yes, there's no public source code for the BMC, which is why it's so hard to find out ... You only included the output of `i2cdetect -l`, what you need to do is probe the bus itself. The Radeon busses are for EDID, while the I801 is on the motherboard, so edit question with output of `i2cdetect -y 8`. Indent four spaces for proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks, updated question to include addresses for i2c-8. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat in the answer what was already mentioned in the comments:

First, identify the present I2C adapters for which there are drivers loaded with `i2detect -l`.

From the name of the adapter one can often guess the function, the `Radeon` adapters are for [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) (Monitor information), and the `SMBus I801` adapter is from the motherboard as part of the southbridge (you'll see it with `lspci`).

Note that the numbering may not be constant accross boots. To find the correct adapter, look at the contents of `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/name`.

The next step is to identify I2C devices connected to a particular adapter. In your case, that is adapter number `8`, so `i2cdetect -y 8` is the necessary command.

EEPROMs *usually* have addresses from `50` to `53`. In general it's pretty difficult to find out what particular chip is connected at a particular address; inspecting the hardware closely, noting the chip numbers and looking for datasheets to narrow down possible I2C addresses helps.

But EEPROMs are fairly standard. You can access the EEPROMS with the kernel `eeprom` driver; after modprobing, the contents will show up under `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers/eeprom/`.

On my motherboard, I have EEPROMs for two DIMM RAMs at `50` and `52`, and I can use the `decode-dimms` program from the Debian `i2c-tools` package to decode the [Vital Product Data (VPD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vital_Product_Data) of the DIMMs.

It's possible that these devices on your system are also just RAM VPDs, and the NVME VPDs are somewhere else. It's also possible that your NVME's uses a different I2C bus on a different adapter, and you don't have the Linux kernel driver loaded for this adapter (or nobody has written such a driver yet).

But at least now you know how to use `i2cdetect` to identify EEPROMs.

**Edit**

As said in the comments, the BMC microcontroller is completely different from the host CPU, and it's possible that it has access to different hardware than the host CPU does. So the answer to "but why can the BMC see it?" is "because it's totally different, and what the BMC can and can't do doesn't necessarily influence what the host CPU can and can't do".

That said, it seems your real question is "how can I access the VPD of NVME on the host CPU". I googled the [NVME Management Interface specification](https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM_Express_Management_Interface_1_0_gold.pdf), and it says Management Endpoints can be both reached via a I2C/SMBus port and a PCIe port.

So my guess would be that the Management Endpoint of your hardware is only reachable via PCIe.

Further googling found a [Management Endpoint CLI](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli) which works via `ioctls` on the Linux `nvme` driver, at least from the quick look at the code I did.

So in your place I'd try this tool to access the Management Endpoint interface on your hardware, and see if you can't get the VPD this way.

I don't have an NVME device here, so I can't test.

Comment: Big thanks for all the replies Sir. Added info, i have 4 DIMMs in my setup. Additionally, for the bus 8, i tried removing my nvme in the pci slot and still the same -y output addresses is displayed. Seems my eeprom is not logged in it. I assume, similar to what you said, that there is a need for an adapter driver, however, it made me go back to the idea that how IPMI can query my eeprom VPD even if it doesnt show the i2c bus or even my eeprom address in i2cdetect. Even if i801 is not modprobed, IPMI can still display the VPD info. Any more ideas Sir? Really appreciate answering all my queries.

Comment: Sir, I'm familiar with that approach on ioctls. Actually, what I want to develop is a dual approach query of accessing VPD and I'm already done with that, these are called in-bound commands. Out-bound commands are via SMBus/I2C. This is what I'm developing for. FYI, in-bound commands requires firmware support whereas out-bound commands can directly access hardware components for information stored on a specific device. Honestly, I already red NVME-MIS and it really burns me out of the idea that it just explains rather than gave me a a thorough code discussion.

Comment: Additional approach I did, I also research on IPMIs open source, or CLIs, up to date, I only have the SMCIPMITool to run via CLI with nvme VPD information. other tools such as IPMITool with open source doesnt have such feature. SMCIPMITool is in java and its package is in binary, no source code so I am having a hard time on looking for how the tool queries such VPD information.